# ModuleNotFoundError with package definition cross project

Tags: python

I define a library with this architecture:

```
group
├── __init__.py
└──package1
    ├── __init__.py
    └── package2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── file1.py
        ├── file2.py
        └── file3.py
```

I package this with the command:

```
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

And finally push it into a repository (artifactory).

In an other project, I get this dependency, defined in a `requirements.txt`, and I can find it in the `venv` folder.
In this project, I have the almost same architecture:

```
group
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└──package1
    ├── __init__.py
    └── package2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── file6.py
        ├── file5.py
        └── ...
```

The problem is: when I run my init test in second project, python complains about `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'group.package1.package2'`.

What did I miss?

Please, if you need more information, don't hesitate to ask ;)

Thanks

Comment: Is it because the top folder has the same name ?

Comment: I think so, but how do I have to configure `__init__.py` (I guess) or `setup.py` to allow this behavior